# {domain...} tokens not parsed in regular mail?

Tags: drupal, email, tokens

Is it me, or are the {domain...} tokens not parsed in a private (non-civimail) mail ? Like, when sending a mail from a contacts page ?

If it isn't me, then the documentation here is wrong ?
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#domainaddress

Drupal 7.56, CiviCRM 4.7.27

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM are you using and CMS?

Comment: @PradeepNayak - sorry - edited the post now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Domain tokens are not replaced when trying to send email activity for a contact. This seems like a bug in civicrm or wrong documentation. This can be fixed by applying below patch.

```
diff --git a/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php b/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php
index 787a1c955d..35133010e1 100644
--- a/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php
+++ b/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php
@@ -1587,6 +1587,12 @@ LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact src ON (src.activity_id = ac.activity_id AND
         $values = array_merge($values, $details["{$contactId}"]);
       }

+      $domainTokens = array_merge($subjectToken, $messageToken);
+      $domain = CRM_Core_BAO_Domain::getDomain();
+      foreach (['subject', 'text', 'html'] as $bodyType) {
+        $$bodyType = CRM_Utils_Token::replaceDomainTokens($$bodyType, $domain, TRUE, $domainTokens, TRUE);
+      }
+
       $tokenSubject = CRM_Utils_Token::replaceContactTokens($subject, $values, FALSE, $subjectToken, FALSE, $escapeSmarty);
       $tokenSubject = CRM_Utils_Token::replaceHookTokens($tokenSubject, $values, $categories, FALSE, $escapeSmarty);
```

Comment: do you know if this is already in the bugtracker ? i can add it.

Comment: No, this is not logged in CiviCRM issue tracker. Please go ahead and log.

Comment: Thank, did that here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21615

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a missing feature is core. The documentation do suggest that custom tokens can be used in non-bulk mailings. However, tokens like actions, mailings are not replaced. One of our client wanted to have domain details send in non-bulk emails, we used [tokens](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/) and [tokenValues](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/) hooks to have {domain.xxx} work.

Comment: I did sort of the same, but now the domain* values are configured in two places :-/