# Smarty template tokens not translating

Tags: smarty

We are running civicrm 5.33.1, wordpress 5.7, php 7.4.

The following test template only translates the contact.email greeting, the others stay as they are as do all other tokens in our templates.

Dear {contact.email_greeting}

{domain.address}

{domain.email}

{domain.phone}

Comment: I have seen advice saying we need to edit civicrm.settings.php and change the following.            if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 0 );
}  by setting it to 1. However when I do this the system just hangs when I click send the email with template.

Comment: Is this the same as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21984/domain-tokens-not-parsed-in-regular-mail ?

Comment: Thank you Demerit. I misunderstood how tokens work and was trying to use system workflow tokens in a user template.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Demerit. I misunderstood how tokens work and was trying to use system workflow tokens in a user template.